# Show continuity of a linear transformation using Closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

Let $T$ be a linear transformation of a Banach space $B$ into a Banach Space $B'$. Let $E \subset B^{'*} $ satisfying -

**A)** $E$ separates points of $B'$ (i.e. for for $x , y \in B' , x \neq y$ there
is some $\phi \in E$ such that $\phi (x) \neq \phi(y)$) .

**B)** For every $\phi \in E$, $\phi \circ T$ is continuous.

I need to show that $T$ is continuous.

Now I suppose I need to use the **Closed Graph theorem** here but I am not getting any clue as to where to go with it.

Comment: Well, you're trying to show that $T$ has closed graph. So suppose $x_n$ is a sequence in $B$ converging to $x$, and $T(x_n)$ converges to $y\in B'$, but $y \ne T(x)$. Then there exists $\phi\in E$ such that $\phi(y)\ne \phi(Tx)$. Can you derive a contradiction by looking at what $\phi(T(x_n))$ is suppose to converge to?

Comment: Thank you for the point out. I was working for $20$ minutes without reward.